# Why doesn't this remove the Key Lookup from the SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

I have a Key Lookup occuring in a SQL Server query. The SQL Server Execution Plan says the object for the Key Lookup is an index, `Table1.PK_TABLE1`. The Output List includes two more columns from Table1. So I decided to create a covering index, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_Table1_CoveringIndex] ON Table1(Column2, Column3)
```

When I run the query, the same Key Lookup is still happening.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should post your query and your actual execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, your index isn't covering since it needed to go back to the clustered index to get information that wasn't present in the non-clustered index. Since you're looking at an execution plan, what columns is the key lookup operator returning? You'd need to put those columns as either indexed or included columns into your index to avoid the key lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, your covering index sounds incomplete. Your index needs to include all of the columns needed for the seek as well as those needed to satisfy the return results.

So, for a query like:

```
SELECT column2, column3
    FROM Table1
    WHERE column1 = @SomeParam;
```

You'd want to "cover" that with:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_Table1_CoveringIndex] ON Table1(Column1, column2, column3);
```

Or perhaps even using included columns:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_Table1_CoveringIndex] ON Table1(Column1) INCLUDE (column2, column3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, more than once, and I still see the Key Lookup. Seems very strange.